# How to find if a value exit, add one if not exist or update if exist

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure on my Firebase

```json
{
    "database": [
        null,
        {
          "_location_id": 1,
          "_location_address": "ABC",
          "_location_county": "CS",
          "_location_description": "N/A"
          "_location_image": 
        },
        {
    
          "_location_id": 2,
          "_location_address": "DEF",
          "_location_county": "BC",
          "_location_description": "djbkdbksbk",
          "_location_image": 
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to identify if I have a record if location_id equal if 2 for example in my Firebase database. If exists, I need to test if it has the same information on this record as on my phone database. If they are the same, skip the step, if not I need to update.

Until now I have next code, but without success.

```java
MESSAGE_REFERENCE.orderByKey().equalTo(row.get(0).toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                //verify if need to do update
                text1.setText("ID exist: " + row.get(0).toString()); // row is readed from phone database
            } else {
                text1.setText("ID not exist: " + row.get(0).toString());
            }
    
          
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
        }
    });
```

Any advice for a hobby programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the `_location_id` property has a value of `2`, you'd use a query like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("database");

ref.orderByChild("_location_id").equalTo(2)...
```

The main changes are:

- This code uses `orderByChild` rather than `orderByKey`, since you want to filter on the `_location_id` child property.
- This code uses a numeric value to filter on rather than the string you passed in, since the value in the database is stored as a number.

In addition, I recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), as using sequential, numeric values as keys is an anti-pattern in Firebase.

Comment: solved. required the parent of _location_id, too.